# OData without HTTP in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, odata

I would like to utilize oData without HTTP.

> Scenario: "Load Balancer" oData-capable service receives requests from
>   clients, puts them into a queue (in serialized form), then "background" workers pick up
>   messages from the queue and process the request (get data from data
>   storage and provide response)

And it seems that such functionality either it is not exposed in MS oData libs, or it is so simple and obvious (*though not for me*) that nobody cares to highlight it in the docs.

I see it something like (pseudo-code)

```
var model = GetEdmModel();
var processor = GetProcessor(); // something like ODataController in AspNet.oData - contains functions and whatever
var request = GetRequestFromQueueAndParse();
var uriPath = request.Path; // like "/Books" 
var queryString = request.QueryString; // like "$filter=price lt 50"
var method = request.Method; // GET or POST or ...
var body = request.Body; 

// *** here is what I am looking for ***
var response = SomeMagicODataHelper.ProcessQuery(model, processor, method, uriPath, queryString, body);

ProvideResponseBackToBalancer(response);
```

Is there something alike provided by (preferable) standard MS oData library, or as a third-party library?

Comment: OData itself is available in Net Core: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/asp-net-core-odata-now-available/ - I'm not sure what your question is?

Comment: The question is how to use awesome features of aspnet.odata, like routing, parsing and so on, without starting http server. Get "request" (in json for example), call appropriate "controller" method and get a result

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. OData is a query language that parses a query string into a linq expression that can be executed on a database. It lives on a server via some sort of WebApi. How do you propose to use OData without it living in a WebApi or on some sort of server? Why would not just use Linq instead if you dont want the server part?

Comment: Well, I thought Scenario I suggested might have clarified the things. Seems like it didn't. Dumb load balancer that gets http requests and puts them into the queue. And background workers that get requests from the queue and process them according to oData specs.

Comment: Ok, so load balancing is a completely different technology for a different thing. Load balancing is the ability to handle multiple requests across multiple servers to increase scalability. OData is a specific method of query translation from a string to  expressions for Entity Framework to fetch data via an IQueryable. OData needs to act on entities directly. Why would you want to have these methods queued?

Comment: another scenario is to use the oData in Azure functions (that support http, but not WebApi)